# Font displaying as squares in terminal preview

Tags: command-line, fonts

I have recently installed inconsolata and now when I go to preview the font it shows up as squares.

[image: Screenshot]

This is a preview form my terminal.

Here are my file permissions:

```
> ls -lh /usr/share/fonts/truetype/inconsolata
total 60K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58K Dec  6  2009 Inconsolata.otf
```

and here is where it is located (truetype fonts folder):

```
> ls -lh /usr/share/fonts/truetype            
total 96K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 abyssinica
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 dejavu
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Nov 17 22:43 droid
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   43 Nov 17 22:09 fonts-japanese-gothic.ttf -> /       /etc/alternatives/fonts-japanese-gothic.ttf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 freefont
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Feb 18 15:20 horai-umefont
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Mar  8 18:01 inconsolata
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 kacst
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 kacst-one
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 lao
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 liberation
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Feb 18 15:23 msttcorefonts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 nanum
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Dec 19 10:11 openoffice
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 padauk
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 sinhala
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 takao-gothic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 tibetan-machine
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 tlwg
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 ttf-indic-fonts-core
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 ttf-khmeros-core
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 ttf-punjabi-fonts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jul 22  2014 ubuntu-font-family
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Feb 18 15:20 unfonts-core
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Feb 18 15:21 wqy
```

Can anyone help me? I'd really like to get this font to work. I have updated my fonts cache via `fc-cache -f -v`, but it hasn't fixed anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've downloaded an OpenType font and stored it in the TrueType font directory.

I've got the exact same font but stored in `/usr/share/fonts/opentype/` and the [Inconsolata PDF test file](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/textest.pdf) displays perfectly after a:

- `sudo fc-cache --force --verbose`
- log out
- log back in...