# After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.4 MultiSSH window showing Unicode charcter(numbers in block), how to resolve it?

Tags: ssh, gnome-terminal

Recently I have upgraded to Ubuntu 20.4 from 18. Before I am able to use Multi SSH(mssh) Package to ssh into multiple servers together. But after upgrade i an seeing Unicode character(number in blocks). Not able to resolve after installing every dependancy and related package from this link:https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/mssh. please provide any answer to slove this:
See this image to know more clear about issue
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font displaying as squares in terminal preview](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595680/font-displaying-as-squares-in-terminal-preview)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 installation gave my terminal all squares with 4 characters in them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239784/ubuntu-20-04-installation-gave-my-terminal-all-squares-with-4-characters-in-them)

Comment: above did't resolved my issue, my issue is with mssh window, my terminal is showing character perfectly, not sure about mssh package. Any other suggestion please.